# Is it possible to transfer an object ownership from Go to C++?

Tags: go, dynamic-memory-allocation, cgo

Imagine that I new a string in Go, and pass its address to C++ program by cgo.
How can I let Go garbage collection ignore the string forever, like the Golang never new this string, and let C++ decide when to free the memory?

I can only pass the Go object pointer to C++.
But I can not prevent Go garbage collection to recycle the object.

Comment: `new()` will allocate memory on an area that is owned and managed by the Go runtime. You cannot pass ownership or responsibility of this to another entity. The memory should be allocated by C++ code, and either the Go code or the C++ code should copy the data there.

Answer (score 0):

If by ignore you mean to free memory allocated by this string: the simple answer is: never use it in your go code again, to not provide GC.

When working with C code in Go, it's important to keep in mind that both Go and C maintain their own separate memory management systems.

GOLANG GC will free up memory for this string. But when you pass it to C, it will also allocate memory for the string and free it only when you explicitly use `defer C.free(someString)`.